# How can I get a json content from another js file?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have two files:

```
// roles.js

export function roles() {
    return {"/": ["admin","user"]};
  }


// router.config.js

import {roles} from '../src/pages/.umi/roles'
console.log(roles['/']);
```

It throws:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '/' of undefined

See? It is undefined. how can I make it accessible?

Comment: are you sure about your path? Did you try to reproduce it using a [mcve] and avoid errors linked maybe to a chunk of code in one of your files?

Comment: Yes the route is correct @UlysseBN

Comment: By the way, why you're xporting a method if is just returning an static value?

Comment: @segu That is not static .. the content of it will be generated per user login

Comment: Are you sure that your server serves files on `../src` path? See this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-47mjrg?file=index.js - if you remove `()` it logs undefined

Comment: roles is a method..... You act like it is an object so once you get the undefined issue out of the way, you will have a new bug. Do you really have a folder with a `.` in the name?

Comment: You need to do: roles()["/"] to get the array you are looking for.  Your path is prob messed up because you might not have the right understanding of where the files directory is running from

Comment: @epascarello Yes the name of it is exactly `.umi`. It's antd-pro framwork I'm using.

Comment: In the end, it looks like the issue is not possible to see here... I'd suggest either to try to update your question with an issue that can be reproduced, either to close it.

Answer (score 1):

One of your mistakes is you're importing a function. 
You should use `roles()['/']` to get value

The other problem about undefined, probably is that you're importing wrong path like they're commenting.

Here you have an example that it runs.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-5cquau

Comment: not sure this is the solution since it throws that `roles` is `undefined`

Comment: but it says '/' of undefined which means that roles is undefined, not a function